# Send simple data from wp7 to winforms application

Tags: winforms, windows-phone-7

I want to send simple data (geolocation data to be precise) from Windows Phone 7 application to a windows forms application and use it, as I'm a total beginner in this field I don't know which tools to use. 
I searched about wcf services and tested this method but there's some issues: the data is sent from the phone application but isn't sent to the winforms application (guess something is missing)

If your know how to do this in a quick way, or have good tutorials I'll be thankful.

**EDIT**

I found this tutorial, it show how to connect directly wp7 application and desktop application without using sockets neither wcf service, I'm wondering if it is really works if the application isn't in localhost.
the like for the tutorial: [wp7 tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173829/Windows-Phone-7-How-to-Communicate-with-a-Desktop)

Comment: How did you test? If you consume the service, you get data back. Its client independent.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and so I created a REST/JSON WCF service hosted in IIS with AppHarbor to provide the data. There's hundreds of ways to do it (Ruby/Heroku, etc..), but that particular one fits well within the Microsoft stack. I also needed to share route data and I used the WCF service to wrap the BingMaps services so that route computations are cached and shared. Considering that I had already created a local model, moving it out of my phone project into a service took less than a few hours (including the usual config hiccups, and forgetting to add the appharbor user to my bitbucket repo).

Consuming the service from WinForms (or any client) shouldn't be an issue as the service knows nothing about the client implementation.

Here's a tutorial from code project. [REST WCF Service with JSON](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON)

Comment: If you would use WCF you could host your WCF service inside Winforms, that would save you from having multiple applications on the PC side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to implement some sort of server side solution which you could upload to on your Windows Phone and download from on your Windows Form application. This could be achieved using a WCF service which was connected to a server side database.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use sockets and communicate directly with your WinForms application. Check [this](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-Sockets.aspx) tutorial on how to use basic sockets on WP7.